# Euler exact sequence for $\mathbb{P}^n$ and toric varieties

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space, co-tangent-space

I would like to understand explicitly the maps in the Euler exact sequence of $\mathbb{P}^n$:

$$0\rightarrow \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^n}^1\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-1)^{n+1}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}\rightarrow 0$$

and more generally of a smooth toric variety:

$$0\rightarrow \Omega_{X_{\Sigma}}^1\rightarrow \bigoplus_{\rho\in\Sigma(1)}\mathcal{O}_{X_{\Sigma}}(-D_{\rho})^{n+1}\rightarrow Pic(X_{\Sigma})\otimes\mathcal{O}_{X_{\Sigma}}\rightarrow 0$$

What is an explicit presentation of the maps in these exact sequences?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I can't tell you anything about toric varieties, but on $\mathbb P^n$ it's easier to use the dual sequence
$$
0 \to \mathcal O \to \mathcal O(1)^{\oplus n+1} \to T_{\mathbb P^n} \to 0.
$$

If I remember everything correctly, the first map sends $1$ to $(x_0,x_1,...,x_n)$, and the second map sends $x_i$ to $x_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$.

Comment: Thank you but I knew the maps for the dual exact sequence. I really would like to have an explicit form for the maps in the exact sequence of the cotangent sheaf.

Comment: For the case $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ see the lemma 7.4.15 of Algebraic Geometry (Andreas Gathmann).

Comment: MathOverflow: [Euler exact sequence for $\mathbb{P}^n$ and toric varieties](https://mathoverflow.net/q/336794). [This answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) provides very reasonable guidelines on [meta-tag:cross-posting].